# ¿Es posible hacer el diagrama lógico de una base de datos usando MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, diagrama-de-flujo

He estado indagando un poco pero no encuentro algo específico que me indique si es posible y cómo realizar el diagrama lógico de una base de datos usando el MySQL Workbench 6.3. Si he podido hacer el físico importando el script de mi base de datos y añadiendo las tablas a mis diagramas, pero lo primero no he sabido cómo hacerlo. Quisiera saber si es posible para no tener que usar otra herramienta ya que este me gusta bastante. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te refieres a esto?

[image: 1]

Teniendo abierto tu proyecto/dB, debes ir a Model > Create Diagram from Catalog Objects y listo...

(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-creating-a-model.html)

Comment: Disculpa he editado mi pregunta en realidad tal y como muestras en tu respuesta es lo que he podido hacer, ese es el diagrama físico y el que me falta es el lógico. Cualquier ayudita será bienvenida

Comment: Probá esto (para generar tu proyecto como .sql):

File > Export > Forward Engineer > SQL CREATE Script

Comment: A ver estoy haciendo mi tesis de Ingenieria y entre la documentación a presentar está el Modelo Lógico y el Físico de mi base de datos. El Físico puedo sacarlo con el workbench con sus diagramas y el lógico lo puedo hacer con otros programas, tu último comentario lo que me permite es sacar el fichero .sql que tiene la estructura de mis tablas, pero en realidad lo que necesito es un diagrama parecido al que me mostrastes en tu respuesta pero que sea para el MODELO LÓGICO. Gracias